# Node, different cache rules for a particular file type

Tags: node.js, cache-control

I am disabling cache for my app like so:

```
app.use(function noCache(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  res.header('Expires', 0);
  next();
});
```

There is a problem using this over HTTPS when using IE: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/992569/font-face-not-working-with-internet-explorer-and-http-header-pragma-no-cache

How can I change the above code to make it not apply to font type files? I think this will solve my issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you disabling cache to begin with?

Comment: Its a web conferencing app. We have different html presentations uploaded that have same file structure and same file names regularly so don't want anything cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [`req.path`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path) against extensions for web fonts (ttf, woff, eot, etc), and skip sending back those headers in that case:

```
const WEBFONT_EXTENSIONS = /\.(?:eot|ttf|woff|svg)$/i;

app.use(function noCache(req, res, next) {
  if (! WEBFONT_EXTENSIONS.test(req.path)) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    res.header('Expires', 0);
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.